# Duplicate Worksheets with New Names

Tags: excel, vba

Would greatly appreciate your help in figuring out this small issue.

I want to duplicate an excel worksheet multiple times with the name i want it to be. I was able to do it by having it ask me what the name should be - but is there a way to do the same just by coding in those 20 or so tab names.

Here is what i have so far -

```
Dim name As String 
Dim x As Integer 
x = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count 

name = Application.InputBox("Put down the name", "Add worksheet") 
If name = "" Then Exit Sub 
Worksheets(1).Copy after:=Worksheets(x) 
ActiveSheet.Name = name
```

Please let me know if that is something that will be possible. Really appreciate your help.

Thanks.

Comment: So how do you want to specify the name? You can simply give it a name like this: ActiveSheet.Name = "my new sheet" but you already know that yes?

Comment: That was my real question. I have a list of names that i want to reference but not sure how to.

Comment: So you can put the list on a worksheet and get them there. Or you can put the list in a text file and get it from there. Or you can type the list directly in the code and do it from there. What do you want to do? I think it will be easiest to put them in a worksheet.

Comment: Ideal would be putting it on the worksheet - I want to have it all centralized in one file. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do a loop.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("WorksheetWithNames")
Dim y As Integer

For y = 1 To 10 ' < enter the number of sheets you want.
    'copy the sheet

    'rename the sheet
    'assuming you have names in column A
    ActiveSheet.Name = ws.Cells(y, 1)

Next
```

Comment: If this answer helps you please click the checkmark to accept it as the answer. You can also upvote if you want.

Comment: THanks so much brother. Definitely helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is a module that you can insert [with link provided here](http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/567-excel-copy-sheets-multiple-times.html)

The gist of it is to do the following:

```
Click Insert > Module, and paste the following code in the Module Window.

     Sub Copier ()
     Dim x As Integer
     x = InputBox("Enter number of times to copy Sheet1")
     For numtimes = 1 To x
     ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Copy _
     After:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
     Next
     End Sub
```